# Error of SAP Crystal Report Runtime 13_0_21 on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, windows-server-2008-r2

I have developed my application on windows 10. where Visual Studio 2013 and crystal report is working fine.

I need to install the developed package on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit, but crystal report version 13_0_21 runtime is not going to install here. It shows following error message. I have tried after installing different version of C++ redistributable but no luck. Please suggest how I can fix theis problem. This is second day I am stuck this issue. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal report version 13_0_20 works good for windows server.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes:

Even the deployment machine is `64bit` but the Crystal Report need the `32bit` runtime to be install.

Its all shares from my own experience.

Good luck!